# How to declare Object prototypes within another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to learn how to do this in a well written way, if you could help show the proper way to achieve this it would be much appreciated! The reason I organized the code in this way is I want everything to be contained ultimately within a single Object, in this case 'Helper'. This top level object needs to be able to have sub-objects that can allow me to easily organize/process information that the top-level object can access.

**Step 1: Let's say I have a Javascript object called Helper:**

```
 function Helper() {
        var hello = "I'm here to help you!";    
        var cleaners = []; //will contain Cleaning objects
      }
```

**Step 2: I want to add some functions to it:**

```
Helper.prototype = {
  constructor:Helper,
  sayHi:function () {
    return this.hello;
  },
  getCleaners:function() {
    return this.cleaners;
  }
}
```

**Step 3: now let's say I want to add an object called Cleaner to Helper**

```
Helper.prototype.Cleaner = function(something) {
     this.something = 'I will clean '+something; // ?
   }
```

-or- (not sure how to do this)

```
Helper.prototype = {
  constructor:Helper,
  sayHi:function () {
    return this.hello;
  },
  getCleaners:function() {
    return this.cleaners;
  },
  Cleaner:function(something) {
   this.something = 'I will clean '+something; // ? does this refer to Helper or Cleaner? Does it work?
  }
}
```

**Step 4: I want to add a toString() function to Cleaner**

```
Cleaner.prototype.toString = function() {
      return 'something: '+this.something; //?
   }
 -or- //not sure how to do this either

  Helper.prototype = {
      constructor:Helper,
      sayHi:function () {
        return this.hello;
      },
      getCleaners:function() {
        return this.cleaners;
      },
      Cleaner:function(something) {
       this.something = 'I will clean '+something; // ? does this refer to Helper or Cleaner? 
      },
      Cleaner.prototype.toString:function() {
          return 'my task: '+this.something; //?
       }
    }
```

**Step 5: this is how I would like to use the Cleaner object**

```
Helper.prototype.doSomething = function(something) {
  var cleaner = new this.Cleaner(something);
  this.cleaners.push(cleaner);
}
```

**Step 6: and how I would like to use the Helper object**

```
var helper = new Helper();
helper.doSomething(something);
console.log(helper.sayHi());
$.each(helper.getCleaners(), function(index, value) {
  console.log($(this).value);
});
```

Comment: If your questions is primarily about `this`: The value of `this` depends on how a function is called **called**. Hence the answer to your comment `? does this refer to Helper or Cleaner? Does it work?` is "it depends". Skimming over the code it seems fine, except that in the constructor you should use `this.x = ...` instead of `var x = ...`

Comment: @FelixKling thanks Felix for the looking at this. The error I get in my console is "Uncaught TypeError: this.Cleaner is not a constructor, so I don't know how to write and access the object embedded within another object's prototype function. Any thoughts on how to resolve the error?

Comment: Oh well, `Cleaner.prototype.toString:function() {` won't work inside the object literal... you'd have to perform any additions to the prototype after the definition, i.e. `Helper.prototype.Cleaner.prototype.toString = ...`

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the suggestion, I tried it, but got this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.

Comment: That means either `Helper` is `undefined` or `Helper.prototype.Cleaner` is `undefined`. Set breakpoints in your code, step through and inspect variables to find out why...

Comment: @FelixKling sorry, I don't understand. If Helper is instantiated, and other methods can be called on it, then I don't know how it could be undefined, and if I have Helper.prototype.Cleaner = function() {... and then call new Cleaner within Helper and it works then isn't it defined as well? It only gives me the undefined error when I declare the Helper.prototype.Cleaner.prototype.toString =

Comment: Can't repro, works without problems: https://jsfiddle.net/726xz2L7/ .